# Linear version of the Theorem of the Riemann's conformal transformation

Tags: complex-geometry, conformal-geometry

How can I demonstrate that a that a R-linear conformal map in the complex plane is  a function in the form $f(z)=α.z$, where $α$ is a fixed complex number.

Comment: You mean a $\mathbb{R}$-linear conformal map? The exponential is a conformal map on the complex plane and it not linear. I'm guessing you want to prove that the differential of a conformal map between riemann surfaces is given by a complex multiplication on the tangent space, which is equivalent to proving that a $\mathbb{R}$-linear conformal map on $\mathbb{C}$ is of the form you want.

Comment: Yes, I think it is it.

Comment: Then show that up to multiplication by a positive real number, you may assme that $f$ preserves distances and orientation, and thus is a rotation.